# Powershell Remove-Item does not delete all items

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a Powershell script that is supposed to delete items that are X days old. It doesnt fully work. It removes some files but not all of the files. When I run the script without `| Remove-Item -Force`, all the files that meet the requirements are displayed. So, I know the `where` statement works.

Why doesn't `Remove-Item -Force` not delete all items that meet the requirements set be the `where` statement, and how can it be fixed?

```
$deleteFiles = Get-Childitem $fullTargetPath -Recurse
| Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: please try to place the -whatif parameter after remove-item  than you see what action is taken.

Comment: `What if: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target ` on all of the items, but they are not removed from the folder.

Comment: Do you get errors for the files it skips?

Comment: Try `Remove-Item -Force` directly on one of the files that gets skipped.

Comment: @Entbark I did it directly on the files, and it worked

Comment: Long shot here, but are the paths close to 248 characters?

Comment: no, they are all under 100 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before the "Remove-Item" add "Foreach".

So for example:

```
$deleteFiles = Get-Childitem $fullTargetPath -Recurse | 
    Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)} | 
    Foreach { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! but I am still confused on why your solution worked, and mine didn't. The `WhatIf` showed that the action was taking place but, it never actually did.